# Nested Parameters, with polymorphic one-to-one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm having an issue, where I'm trying to add an Address to a Person, using a form on my `#new`-action, as usual.
What I'm doing currently, is

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :owner

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end
```

In my form, I'm using `form_for @person do |f|` - then the form, and then `f.fields_for :address do |af|` and the fields, using `af.text_field`.

My controller action:

```
def create
  person = Person.new(person_params)

  if person.valid?
    person.save
    redirect_to edit_content_person_path(@current_work_context, person)
  else
    @person = person
    render 'new'
  end
end

def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit( :name, :address => [:line_one, :line_two, :zipcode, :city])
end
```

When I submit my form, with these parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"blablabla==",
 "person"=>{"name"=>"mr man",
 "address"=>{"line_one"=>"test address 15",
 "line_two"=>"",
 "zipcode"=>"2600",
 "city"=>"Glostrup"}},
 "locale"=>"da",
 "context_id"=>"9"}
```

Yet, I get the exception: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`

```
Address(#70198415678880) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70198414055220)
```

I cannot seem to figure out why.

EDIT - My view, simplified:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :address do |af| %>
    <%= af.label :address %>
    <%= af.text_field :line_one, :placeholder => "Address 1" %>
    <%= af.text_field :line_two, :placeholder => "Address 2" %>

    <%= af.label :zipcode %>
    <%= af.text_field :zipcode, :class => "form-control" %>

    <%= af.label :city %>
    <%= af.text_field :city, :class => "form-control" %>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know on what line you are getting this error.

Comment: Oh yeah - right. 

On the `Person.new`-line

Comment: very strange. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with  `f.fields_for :address` should transform you params to like that  ...`"person"=>{"name"=>"mr man",
 "address_attributes"=>{"line_one"=>"test address 15"`

Comment: Exactly. I cant quite figure out why it doesn't. My only thought is, that I'm using a polymorphic relationship from Address to Owner, and that Person is an Owner.. @BrenoPerucchi

Comment: this is not the problem. I use here the same implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let trys one thing. Please and this lines and restart your server

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|'
  inflect.irregular 'address', 'addresses'
end
```

## edit

```
# after we discussing more about the problem in chat we found the solution. 
# The object 'Person' not initialize correctly to f.fields_for :address

# view

<% f.object.build_address if f.object.address.blank? %> #add this line 
<%= f.fields_for :address do |af| %>
```

Comment: No success, sadly. I get the same exception.

Comment: only difference for your implementation than mine is the name of class `addresses.rb`  and my has_many is this way `has_many :addresses, class_name: 'Addresses', as: :addressable`

Comment: I have the same in other class. User.rb  has_one :addresses  ... I still think that the problem is the inflection. Edit you post and show the view

Comment: Added the view in OP

Comment: Your view is correct. Try this in your `inflection.rb`  `inflect.uncountable "address"` and comment the other line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120955/discussion-between-breno-perucchi-and-frederik-spang).

Comment: @FrederikSpang our solution is described correctly in the #edit ?